# Get traceback class

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback, built-in-types

I want to apply type hints to a class' `__exit__` method.

```py
class Foo:

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        print(typ, value, traceback)
        print(type(typ), type(value), type(traceback))
        print(type(traceback).__module__)


def main():

    with Foo():
        raise ValueError('Oops.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

While the parameter `type` is of type `type`, and `value` is of type `BaseException`, `traceback` appears to be a built-in class `traceback`.
How can I import this class `traceback` so that I can write:

```py
class Foo:

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ: type, value: BaseException, traceback: traceback):
        print(typ, value, traceback)
        print(type(typ), type(value), type(traceback))
        print(type(traceback).__module__)
```

?

Comment: EDIT: nvm, it's, im dumb `from types import TracebackType`

Comment: Unless you are calling `__exit__` explicitly, there's no need to annotate it.